# Определение GPS координат также динамично, точно и быстро как в приложении Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, gps

Есть много примеров как реализовать определение текущих координат, но я не нашел толковых рабочих, что бы хоть приблизительно воспроизводили функционал определения координат реализованный в Google Maps App т.е открыл приложение оно шуршит и дает тебе максимально точное из возможного местоположение за минимально-оптимальное время.
Накидайте пожалуйста ссылок на толковые реализации требуемого функционала.

Если вы не знаете толковых на ваш взгляд решений, не блокируйте вопрос, проходите мимо.

Comment: А вы не боитесь что вам дадут ссылки на те решения, которые вы посчитали не толковыми? Кстати а что именно было не так в тех решениях?

Comment: Вы меня извините за прямоту вопроса, конечно. Вы просите за вас погуглить, оценить варианты, выбрать лучшие, сделать организованный список с рецензиями и его опубликовать?

Answer (score 2):

в манифест добавить permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Главная активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private FusedLocationProviderApi fusedLocationProviderApi;
    private Location mLastLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getLocation();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    private void getLocation() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(3000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        fusedLocationProviderApi = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                mLastLocation = location;
            }
        };
        fusedLocationProviderApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(Const.TAG, "onConnectionSuspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(Const.TAG, "onConnectionFailed");
    }
}
```

При получении координат сработает `onLocationChanged`.
Естественно надо предварительно проверить чтобы на телефоне была включена в настройках служба определения координат, и заставить пользователя его включить если она отключена.